# Ansible Gitlab Pipeline output to CLI AND Junit

Tags: junit, ansible, gitlab-ci, stdout

I have an gitlab pipeline that runs a very basic ansible playbook. Within the ci file I set the env variables to output to a Junit file.

```
- export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=junit
- export JUNIT_OUTPUT_DIR="results"
```

While giving me a nice readable report at the end of the run in the tests section, this however robs me of being able to see where in the run my playbook is, what server its running on atm etc in the stdout cli. With a job that can take hours to run, it would be nice to be able to get an sense of where it is in its run.

Is there any way to have my cake and eat it? Can I have the stdout, AND still generate the Junit report, or are they mutually exclusive? I've done some reading that states you can only have one **DEFAULT** Callback, the wording seems to suggest it might be possible, but my searching has yet to find an example of how. Help me hive mind, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#setting-a-callback-plugin-for-ansible-playbook),

> You can only have one plugin be the main manager of your console
> output. If you want to replace the default, you should define
> CALLBACK_TYPE = stdout in the subclass and then configure the stdout
> plugin in ansible.cfg.

In other words: you can use any number of callback plugins, but no more than one of them is allowed to have its `CALLBACK_TYPE` set to `stdout`, and you should name this plugin in the `stdout_callback` ansible.cfg setting (`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` environment variable), versus naming the rest of the callback plugins you're using in `callbacks_enabled` (`ANSIBLE_CALLBACKS_ENABLED`).

The documentation doesn't go into any further detail about what `CALLBACK_TYPE` is or what its value is for each of the builtin callback plugins, but it's fairly easy to spot in [the source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/44dcfde9b84177e7dfede11ab287789c577b82b5/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/junit.py#L136). Notably, the junit plugin does **not** have a `CALLBACK_TYPE` of `stdout`.

Ultimately this means you can leave `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` as its default value (which will restore your stdout output) and instead invoke the `junit` plugin using `ANSIBLE_CALLBACKS_ENABLED`.

---

tl;dr:

```
- export ANSIBLE_CALLBACKS_ENABLED=junit
- export JUNIT_OUTPUT_DIR="results"
```